# QGIS Templates don't save guides or page size

Tags: qgis-3, template

I have created a template to fit inside my companies report template which is 8.5x11" page size but with headers/footers. The template page size is 6.5x8.46" in order to fit perfectly inside the report page without scaling anything.

When I open a new composer with the same template the page size defaults to 8.5x11 and no guides come along for the title block.

Is there something I am missing, or is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: That's probably how it's currently programmed, but it doesn't seem like it's supposed to be that way. It was probably an oversight. I suggest making a feature request or bug report (seems like it's in the gray area between current bug vs new feature). https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything.

As per my experience these values are currently not loaded or even saved when you load a template, a sort of bug in my opinion. This happens not only with page size but also with units and other properties.

I found a fix by adjusting these values in template file manually. Open this file in any editor and change the values to the desired parameters e.g. Size of LayoutItem . Below is an example to change the units from **mm** to **in** which doesn't work when you save it with GUI.

Find the line

> LayoutItem size="297,210,mm"

and replace with

> LayoutItem size="11.693,8.268,in"

or any other desired values. Save it and then open it in QGIS. Now you will see your desired changes.